# Find the image under linear mapping for function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations

> Find the image of $(x - 1)^2 + y^2 = 1$ under $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with $(u, v) = F(x, y) = \bigg (\frac{1}{2}(x + y), \frac{1}{2}(-x + y) \bigg )$

I'm not sure how to approach this? Do I solve for $y$ and plug it in?

Comment: It is the circle with radius $\sqrt{2}/2$ and center $(1/2,-1/2).$

Comment: @ReinerMartin, I need help with the approach

Comment: One way (not elegant) is to write the original curve, which is a circle with radius 1 around $(1,0)$ in parametric form $f(t)=(\cos(t)+1,\sin(t))$ and then apply $F$ to it.

Answer (score 0):

The original curve is a circle with radius $1$ around $(1,0),$ which can be parametrized by $f(t)=(\cos(t)+1,\sin(t)).$ It you apply $F$ to it you get $$F(f(t))=\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos t+\sin t,-1-\cos t+\sin t).$$

Moreover,
$$F(f(t+\pi/4))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cos t,-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\sin t\right).$$ This is the circle with radius $1/\sqrt{2}$ and center $(1/2,-1/2).$